# During Pytorch tutorial a ModuleNotFoundError: ‘pycocotools._mask’ occurs

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytorch, torchvision

Hello I’m new to Pytorch and I’ve been trying to work through this tutorial.
[https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/blob/master/intermediate_source/torchvision_tutorial.rst]

I’m using Visual Studio Code, conda installed the Pytorch. Initially the issue was that it was missing the module engine. But this problem was solved here:
So how do we get the references/detection/ folders? What should we download and install? I have installed the pytorch, torchvision in my environment, but I could not find those files. Thanks
With a step I misread.
So I downloaded and copied the pycocotools into the project directory and the vision/detection/ .py files in to it too.
That being done it fixed that issue but the error it is now giving is.

```
(base) C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Project\Test\Tutorial>D:/Anaconda/python.exe c:/Users/Sean/Desktop/Project/Test/Tutorial/tv-training-code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Sean/Desktop/Project/Test/Tutorial/tv-training-code.py", line 13, in <module>
    from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
  File "c:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Project\Test\Tutorial\engine.py", line 8, in <module>
    from coco_utils import get_coco_api_from_dataset
  File "c:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Project\Test\Tutorial\coco_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pycocotools import mask as coco_mask
  File "c:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Project\Test\Tutorial\pycocotools\mask.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pycocotools._mask as _mask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools._mask'
```

I’m not quite sure what the issue here is or how to fix it. Given that the _mask.pyx is present and is what I think is being imported. As I said I’m not to sure what the issue is but I would appreciate the help.

Python Version : 3.7.4
Pytorch: 1.2.0 (Cuda 10)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you copied the files for `pycocotools` instead of installing them. Files ending in `.pyx` are Cython files which need to be installed into extension modules (on Windows these would be a `.pyd` file). If you do an installation of the package instead of a file copy that should fix your problem.